# How to check if a polygon contains another polygon in OL3?

Tags: openlayers, algorithm

Is there any possibility to check if a polygon is contained in another polygon in OL3?

I noticed there is a couple of methods in ol.extent e.g. ol.extent.containsExtent(extent1, extent2). But this checks only the extents and not the entire polygon. So in some cases I get "true" although the polygon is way outside the other polygon, but still in the extent...
What I need is a function or algorithm that checks if a polygon entirely contains another polygon like I usually do in any GIS.

Comment: You should try JSTS library for that. I think native openlayers 3 have no support yet. Also similler question with answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967711/how-to-check-if-a-polygon-contains-another-polygon-in-ol3.

P.S: There is also this Turf.js for geometrical operation with openlayers 3 geojson feature support but i think it lacks the "contains".